# Parsing JSON from php://input and iterating through object

Tags: php, json

So using javascript I http.send a php script a stringified JSON like so:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", "./SubmitConfigJSON.php", true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ConfigJSON="{"
ConfigJSON=ConfigJSON+"\""+document.getElementsByName("ConfigVars")[0].id+"\":\""+document.getElementsByName("ConfigVars")[0].innerHTML+"\"";
for (var i = 1; i < document.getElementsByName("ConfigVars").length; i++){
  ConfigJSON=ConfigJSON+",\""+document.getElementsByName("ConfigVars")[i].id+"\":\""+document.getElementsByName("ConfigVars")[i].innerHTML+"\"";
};
ConfigJSON=ConfigJSON+"}"
http.send(ConfigJSON);
```

The JSON itself is simple...  Something like this:

```
{"username":"joebob","nocfilelocation":"noc1.xmp"}
```

...And send it to a PHP script with the intention that the PHP script will

1. Import the JSON into an object or array
2. Iterate through the object or array writing the value to a file with the name of the aforementioned value's key.

Somehow in fleshing out this PHP I've worked myself into a corner!

This works:

```
<?php
//writes the json string to a file
$ConfigJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$myfile = fopen("dropfile", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $ConfigJSON);
fclose($myfile);

//imports a json string from a file and iterates through it, writing values to files with filenames based on their keys.
$ConfigJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('./dropfile'));
foreach ($ConfigJSON as $key => $value){
  $myfile = fopen("$key", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  fwrite($myfile, $value);
  fclose($myfile);
};
?>
```

But I'd prefer to just import the PHP input and then iterate through that without writing a file in-between.  Something like...

```
$ConfigJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
foreach ($ConfigJSON as $key => $value){
  $myfile = fopen("$key", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  fwrite($myfile, $value);
  fclose($myfile);
};
```

...But this does NOT work.  I'm sure I'm missing something REALLY simple here.

Comment: The example that doesnt work - what errors do you get?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does it do, what doesn't it do? Any specific errors? Have you inspected your variables (`var_dump`) to see what they contain? There should be no reason why writing it to a file and reading it back should change anything. In fact, it's very weird that this *should* work, since you're trying to write an object into a file which should fail.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied foreach()  What does it do?  Nothing.  What doesn't it do?  Anything.  ...And regardless of how weird it appears it does in fact work and perhaps that is the nature of the problem.  Writing it into a file produces a file with the exact contents of the JSON sent to it with http.send(JSON.stringify(ConfigJSON)).  I'm currently investigating how to inspect the var_dump of the php...

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.  It was the JSON.stringify.  The JSON object was transformed to "{/"filename1/":/"filecontents1/",/"filename2/":/"filecontents2/"}".  Writing it to a file de-stringified it so-to-speak.  So without JSON.stringify it posts the JSON to the php and the latter example now works as I wanted it to.  Since I'm posting to the PHP with http.post debugging involved file writes instead of var_dump or echoing.

Comment: Honestly, I've been getting great help with any coding question for YEARS now thanks to great sites like StackOverflow and a little Google-Fu...  Got stumped on the double-stringify and figured "Well, I'll post this and see if someone can answer the question before I figure it out."...  And this is why after a decade I still have a reputation of 1 on StackOverflow!   LOL!  Maybe someone can tell me if there's any danger to writing files in this way or any future pitfalls I might encounter or something...  Who knows?

Answer (score 1):

If `file_get_contents('php://input')` would result in the JSON object you expect, your code should fail miserably at `fwrite($myfile, $ConfigJSON)`. The fact that it doesn't and the fact that it works when you again do `json_decode(file_get_contents('./dropfile'))` can mean only one thing:

You're double encoding your JSON.

Likely `http.send()` will JSON encode your data. Since you're doing `JSON.stringify(ConfigJSON)` yourself already, your JSON encoded data is wrapped in yet another JSON layer, which means you also need to `json_decode` it twice to get an object back.

Tip: use `var_dump($var)` on all relevant variables to inspect what's in them. Don't *guess*, *see*. To see its results in an AJAX request, look at your browser's developer tool's network inspector tab and inspect the details of the AJAX request.

Comment: I was suspecting that `ConfigJSON` has been JSON encoded before it reached the statement quoted in the question, but double encoding is certainly the problem here.

Comment: I beat you to the answer, but good job though!  Darn refresh, huh?  Don't totally agree with your answer although it is generally correct.  http.send() does not encode data and by some more nit-picky level neither does JSON.stringify().  At best it can be described as serialization although that is even more debatable.  Fault lies on me though for not posting ALL of my code, which is where the problem actually was.  The JSON.stringify was being applied to a string I concatenated in JSON format already, so Quentin is also correct except for the whole "encoding" reference, in my opinion.

Comment: @Danny Encoding, serialisation... to-may-to, to-mah-to... :P

Comment: LOL.  That kind of attitude is maybe why you think http.send() encodes data!  And posting an answer after I had already posted it seems also bad hat as well.  As for var_dump I am interested in how you might implement that in an XMLhttp post request?  My solution which brought about my double-stringify realization involved changing the PHP to write the PHP input to a file, at what point I noticed the extra quoting and double-quote escapes.  Does var_dump return data to a file on the PHP server (I'm running it) or to the poster in any way?

Comment: @Danny No, my suggestion about `http.send()` stemmed from the fact that you nowhere specified what `http` is exactly, so the best I can do is guess. It was off the mark, but close enough, given virtually no information. It's not an "attitude" and it certainly is not a problem, it's practical troubleshooting. I'm also pretty sure we were writing an answer at virtually the same time. And again, you can debug AJAX requests **with your browser's developer tools' network inspector**, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I assumed that http.send() being a part of an XMLHttpRequest was just common knowlege as I am not aware of any other instance where one would use http.send(), so my bad there...  I just tried var_dump to inspect the response on the http post request and that does seem useful.  I assumed only the http_response_code was returned in the response on an XMLHttpRequest and that's a bit more informative than writing the dump to a file, so kudos there.  I'd prefer to just delete this question and all record of my stupidity, but since so many have gone to the trouble to respond I'll amend it instead.

Comment: If anyone's wondering as well I've deemed this a security risk anyway and a huge waste of time versus my previous model.  PHP shouldn't write a file with filename and contents dictatable by JSON apparently.  Thanks to johanesse for pointing that out!